# Did i commit Kufr please answer my question

Tags: halal-haram

Salam Alaykum last day i was listening to Quran but then i felt something in my awrah and i touched my awrah with my phone and my phone had a page of Quran on. Did i commit Kufr and this was done unintentionally

Answer (score 0):

In the name of God

The answer is No. You should understand that god doesn't punish anyone because of the things that he/she has done unintentionally, if he is really fair.

Answer (score 0):

Salaam,
Of course you did not commit kufir. Firstly, your intentions were not bad. Secondly, it was an accident. You have to remember that Islam is easy and we ourselves make it difficult. Do not dwell on little things like this because always remember that Shaitan will try to always distract us, especially when we are trying to increase our imam as you were doing by listening to Qur'an. Always remember: “Allah desires ease for you, not hardship.” [The Qur'an (2:185)]. Hope that helps!
Best,
MuslimGap